# increase the performance of web site?

Tags: asp.net, performance, web

When designing a ASP.net WebForm application what are some important steps to take (or hacks if you like to use the term) to ensure the best possible performance (in terms of speed, stability, and scalability)?

Comment: If you care so much for speed, stability and scalability you might first question whether ASP itself is a good compromise..

Comment: @dendini: Do you have any information to back up that statement?  ASP.NET seems to scale just fine.

Comment: there's tons of metrics on the web and most are contradictory, Java JSP however seems to perform particularly good. As for scaling, if you plan to always stay with Microsoft systems might be ok, but if you plan scaling on other operating system ASP might come quite short.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you care so much for speed, stability and scalability you might first question whether ASP itself is a good compromise

Answer (score 4):

1. Avoid round trips to server
2. Wherever possible user `AJAX` calls.
3. Implement Caching.
4. Avoid using Viewstate wherever possible

For further more read these links.

- [Improve Web Application Performance](http://dotnetslackers.com/articles/aspnet/ImproveWebApplicationPerformance.aspx)
- [ASP.NET Web Site Performance Improvement](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/36749/ASP-NET-Web-Site-Performance-Improvement)

Answer (score 3):

Since so many things can affect performance, it's difficult to provide such a list.  We may make assumptions about your code that aren't correct, and may focus on the wrong areas while you suffer poor performance from something we would otherwise take for granted.

Having said that, in general you might keep an eye on:

- Don't over-use ViewState.  (I'd argue not to use it *at all*, but that's another issue entirely.)
- Keep page resources small (minified text, good image encoding, etc.).
- Ensure page resources are properly cached once downloaded.
- Try to move most UX logic client-side.  (Avoid post-backs for things you can otherwise do in JavaScript, fetch data asynchronously where possible in small chunks, etc.)

The list can go on and on, and that's just with the web tier of the application.  You could easily encounter site performance problems resulting from slow server-side code or server-side resource dependencies (database, etc.) that can't be debugged in the browser.

So the main point is to learn your debugging tools.  Through combinations of browser tools (FireBug, Chrome Developer tools, etc.), Visual Studio debugging (or whatever else you may use for your .NET code), good logging, and even profiling tools you can identify your bottlenecks and tweak your system accordingly.

Comment: If we are looking specifically at the WebForms design side of things then I agree with everything @David says. All of the points he has bulleted are extremely important. You might also want to download the free ebook from here: http://apps.developermedia.com/click/25475?_z=2201303074849724

Answer (score 1):

Check your website in google page speed :[click](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights)

It will give your problem . for unwanted style.images and etc.......

Answer (score 0):

when it comes to performance of the web application we need to consider many things this article will help you understand what performance is where to start.
In web application 80 percent of the time it is front end which requires performance optimization, what needed to be optimized is a big question and really hard to answer
this article i found will help you understand the web performance optimization
[Web Performance Optimization](http://blog.naveedcs.com/2014/08/06/understanding-web-performance-web-performance-optimization/)